# Set Odometry and SetModelState

Tags: odometry

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

For repeated tests, I want to move my robot back to (0,0). I've been using SetModelState, but that does not reset the odometry. Is there a way to reset the odometry easily?

I found LAYER_POSITION2D_REQ_SET_ODOM [here](https://bitbucket.org/osrf/gazebo/src/94f55b2d75427f933bc554aa7b28bf8f4c7e8213/interfaces/player/Position2dInterface.cc) but it's unclear how to use it from ROS.

**Edit**: I'm using the basic PR2 setup in conjunction with ROS. I create an empty world and spawn a PR2 in it. The /base_odometry/odom topic is published by the /gazebo node.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/3110/set-odometry-and-setmodelstate/) by [David Lu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/153/david-lu/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 111 on 2013-06-03

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ffurrer](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/28/ffurrer/) on 2013-06-03**:
what robot and which odometry are you talking about? Where do you get the odometry from, a plugin?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

Hi David,

PR2 odometry information is published by a [ROS odometry controller](https://code.ros.org/svn/wg-ros-pkg/stacks/pr2_controllers/trunk/pr2_mechanism_controllers/src/pr2_odometry.cpp).  All controllers in gazebo are loaded through a [gazebo plugin](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_gazebo_plugins?distro=groovy#gazebo_ros_controller_manager) that mimics the [PR2 controller manager](http://ros.org/wiki/pr2_controller_manager) on the robot.  Gazebo itself does not keep odometry information.

John

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/6/hsu/) with karma: 1873 on 2013-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1